# use the same javascript functions in all rows to get date and time

Tags: javascript

every time i click on add entry i generate a row with the same buttons and use the same functions but for date and time only work once you add the first row. I want to use the same function for the rest of rows

//the table itself

```
<table id="table_data" class="table table-stripped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Date | Time</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Reading</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-2">Remarks</th>
                    <th class="col-sm-1">Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

//JQuery add entry

```
$('#add_entry').click(function () {
    var newRowContent = '<tr><td><select id="selectNumber" name="day" onmouseover="dayGet()"><option>-D-</option></select><select id="selectTime" name="time" onmouseover="AddEventHandler()"><option>-T-</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="reading" class="numbersOnly" onkeypress="validate(event)" /></td><td><input type="text" name="remark" /></td><td><button type="button" name="delete_row" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></button></td></tr>';
    $('#table_data > tbody').append(newRowContent);

function getTime(){
    var select = document.getElementById("selectTime");
    var options = 25;
    for(var i = 1; i < options; i++) {
        var opt = i;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the  problem??

Comment: I am trying to reuse the same function more than once. I have a table where in each row i have to dropdown and select the time but it only works in the first row and not the rest since it is calling the same function

Answer (score 2):

Use addEventListener() method in this case if you're using plain javascript.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    // code
    alert('event called');
});
```

For reference: Follow http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

in jQuery: you just need to trigger event by selecting any element like this

```
$('selector').event({
    // code
    alert('event called');
});
```

For reference: Follow http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

Comment: can you please direct me how i am new to javascript

Comment: Just copy that in your end of the html page in <script> tag or inside external js file.
Inside the //code part you will need to call your function which is getTime();

Comment: can you do a code rewrite of my code that would be really helpful to understand the addEventListener

Comment: I have been able to do it but it is not the way i wanted